# 'dimnames error' depending on colnames filling order

Tags: r, matrix

This piece of code works fine:

```
MATRIX_RESULT_CSV <- matrix(NA,nrow=1,ncol=5)
colnames(MATRIX_RESULT_CSV)[3:5]   <- c("3", "4", "5")
colnames(MATRIX_RESULT_CSV)[1:2]   <- c("1", "2")
```

Yet when the furst columns is filled first it produces a 'dimname error':

```
MATRIX_RESULT_CSV <- matrix(NA,nrow=1,ncol=5)
colnames(MATRIX_RESULT_CSV)[1:2]   <- c("1", "2")
colnames(MATRIX_RESULT_CSV)[3:5]   <- c("3", "4", "5")

Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("1", "2")) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

I am looking at the underneath reason.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the underlying reason, but interstingly this works:

```
MATRIX_RESULT_CSV <- matrix(NA,nrow=1,ncol=5)
colnames(MATRIX_RESULT_CSV) = rep(NA, ncol(MATRIX_RESULT_CSV))
colnames(MATRIX_RESULT_CSV)[1:2] = c("1","2")
```